# Is one allowed to publicize stories about Rabbis without asking them first?

Tags: halacha-theory, rabbis, agada-stories-legends, hasidic-story

THe approach of learning Halochos or Middos or behaviors from observing Tzaddikim's behavior alone is very common in our literature and is even rooted in Gemmorah ([Brochos 62](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Berakhot.62a.1?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Aramaic&lang=bi)):

> תניא אמר רבי עקיבא פעם אחת נכנסתי אחר רבי יהושע לבית הכסא ולמדתי ממנו שלשה דברים
>
> It was taught in a baraita in tractate Derekh Eretz that Rabbi Akiva said: I once entered the bathroom after my teacher Rabbi Yehoshua, and I learned three things from observing his behavior:

Multiple stories describe Rabbis' behaviors and numerous conclusions are drawn without asking the source for explanations, clarifications or comments.

How Halachic is it - did our Rabbis themselves reflect on this subject?

Comment: there is a concept of maaseh rav

Comment: I don't see how the title of your question matches the body of your question. Also, we learn things from the Avos. The Torah publicizes their actions so we can learn from them

Answer (score -1):

If you could ask the rabbis' permission, I would recommend that you do. If not, then their descendants, and in the event that this is no longer attainable, I would refer to the slogan, "for educational purposes only." In this light, I assume you could publish, but take that with a grain of salt and consult with your lawyer first and then your rabbi.

Comment: Sorry I didn't make myself clear, I added a clarification. Please edit your answer accordingly. Also, we seek for sourced answers, that what the Q. asked.

Comment: @AlBerko How many times do I have to tell you that site policy is not to edit questions after they’ve been answered such that the answers are invalidated? I’m rolling back your edit accordingly.

Comment: @AlBerko What was your question again?

Comment: @DonielF How many times was I criticized that this kind of unsourced and shallow comment does not constitute an answer? So instead of me copying the question over, let's agree that you convince Jonathan to withdraw the answer and I'll edit the question.

Comment: @AlBerko I agree with you regarding this being a bad answer to your original question, but it was still an answer. Two wrongs don’t make a right.

Comment: @DonielF that policy only applies if there is an upvoted answer https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1231/759 which there currently isn't

Comment: How does this answer the question?